# using JQuery plugins with Grails resources plugin

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-plugins, groovy, resources

What's the best/easiest way to include a JQuery plugin like [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) in an app that uses the Grails resources plugin?

The FancyBox plugin includes .js, .css, and image files. In this plugin, it's assumed that the image and .css files are in the same directory

In general, it's also possible that the .js files have references to the image and .css files. In a Grails app, I would like to put the .css files under `/web-app/css/fancybox`, the .js files under `/web-app/js/fancybox` and the image files under `/web-app/images/fancybox`, and declare a resources module for them

```
modules = {
    fancybox {
        dependsOn 'jquery'

        resource '/js/fancybox/foo.js'
        resource '/css/fancybox/bar.css'
        resource '/images/fancybox/bg.png'
        // etc.
    }
}
```

But I expect this will break the references among the files in the plugin. Is there a series of steps I can follow to create a module for a JQuery plugin, that allows me to store the resources in an appropriate place (e.g. plugin CSS resources under `web-app/css/pluginName`), that doesn't require me to manually update the paths in the plugin?

Comment: if you use resources plugin _all_ resources will be located at /static/*, so they will be in one folder by default. You can include resources from plugins by using `resource (url: [plugin: 'fancyBox', dir: '/css', file: 'adsf.js'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your last question is probably no. But how about releasing a grails plug in for this? That would service the community and keep your app clean, even if the plugin was a bit messy with all the files in the same folder.

UPDATE

I was just doing some related work and realized that you should be OK to distribute the files as you want because at run time, the Resources plugin will put all the files in `<app>/static/`.

But I still think a plugin would be a good idea.

Comment: If the resources plugin puts all resources in `/static` at runtime how does it handle an app that has `/js/foo/foo.js` and `/js/bar/foo.js`?