# Adding in Jquery Plugins Grails

Tags: jquery, grails

Similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614627/using-jquery-plugins-with-grails-resources-plugin)

So I am trying to implement a Jquery based plugin [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in my grails project. However, I am not quite sure how to include all the resources in my project. Previous plugins I have used just have a single .js file, which I place in my web-app/js folder, and just use the `g:javascript` tag to reference these individual files. However, this plugin includes quite a few javascript files, so I was wondering if there was a way to just specify the directory they are located in, instead of including every single file individually. Using the `g:javascript` tag only seems to work with individual files, and not if I specify a directory

Do I have to go through and manually add each individual filepath for each file( bit of a pain), or is there someway I can declare a resource module that automatically includes the entire directory?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare a new resource inside ApplicationResouces.groovy and list all the js files in there. That way you can re-use the resources in different layouts.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html

Also, take a look at the replacement for the resources plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline

I haven't had a change to use it yet, but from what I hear it is more robust than the resources plugin

Answer (score 0):

The new workflow (starting with Grails 2.4.x) would be to use the Grails Asset Pipeline Plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline

http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

Just declare your application.js like this:

```
//= require jquery
```

With all jQuery files in the jQuery folder inside your js directory.

After this you can include the files into your gsp like this:

```
<head>
  <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
  <asset:stylesheet href="application.css"/>
</head>
```